# Getting the full name in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

So I am editing my .bashrc file (the one used when I log in) and I want to have it so it outputs "Hello FIRSTNAME LASTNAME (USER)."

I know how to access the user using $USER and get that part. Currently I have the FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME stored in variables but I wondering if there was any way to retrieve my actual first and last name.

I've tried `getent passwd USER` but that gives me more than I want.

So, is there a simple way to get the firstname and lastname or will I have to resort to manually entering it in?

Thanks.

Comment: Split the result of `getent` and get the full name from there. AFAIK, it's the only place where user full names are stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FULLNAME=$(getent passwd $USER | cut -d : -f 5)
```

By the way, splitting full name into first and last name is a very bad idea, there are many people in this world where their full name doesn't split into those two categories.

Comment: Falehoods Programmers Believe About Names: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/